# 3d tikz picture wrong overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create this drawing:

[image: Target output]

So with Tikz I use:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{60}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3,thick]

    % Body
    \draw (0,-1/2,0) -- (0,-1/2,1) -- (0,1/2,1) -- (0,1/2,0) -- cycle;

    % XZ plane
      \def\y{0}
      \draw[thin,red,fill=red] (0,\y,-.1) --
      (0,\y,1.1) --(1,\y,1.1) --
      (1,\y,-.1)  -- cycle;

    % XY plane
    \def\z{0.5}
      \draw[thin,green,fill=green] (0,-.6,\z) -- (1,-.6,\z) --
      (1,.6,\z) -- (0,.6,\z) --cycle;

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Two planes}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which produces this:
[image: Tikz Output]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The problem is that you are using the [painter's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm) to render the 3D scene. It's well known that it does *not* work when objects intersects/overlap.

Answer (score 5):

The top part of the red plane is in the foreground and the bottom part is in the background, so don't think using just layers will work.

A simple fix is to redraw the top portion of the red plane after the green plane is draw using

```
\draw [thin,red,fill=red] (0,\y,\z) -- (1,\y,\z) -- (1,\y,1.1) (1,\y,-.1)  -- cycle;
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{60}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=3,thick]

    % Body
    \draw (0,-1/2,0) -- (0,-1/2,1) -- (0,1/2,1) -- (0,1/2,0) -- cycle;

    \def\y{0}
    % XZ plane
      \draw[thin,red,fill=red] (0,\y,-.1) --
      (0,\y,1.1) --(1,\y,1.1) --
      (1,\y,-.1)  -- cycle;
    
    
    % XY plane
    \def\z{0.5}
      \draw[thin,green,fill=green] (0,-.6,\z) -- (1,-.6,\z) --
      (1,.6,\z) -- (0,.6,\z) --cycle;
    
    
    \draw [thin,red,fill=red] (0,\y,\z) -- (1,\y,\z) -- (1,\y,1.1)
    (1,\y,-.1)  -- cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Two planes}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not quite get your double negation : ..."so don't think using just layers won't work". Do you want him to use layers? -or just your simple solution?

Comment: @Hans-PeterE.Kristiansen: Thanks for point that out. Have corrected.

Comment: Thanks for that. My issue is that the drawing is actually a much-simplified version of what the final thing would look like. It sounds like this can't be done in tikz though?

Comment: Of course it _can_ be done. Just a matter of how you want to specify what you desire. Perhaps you should post a more general question about what you are trying to do. This was just one solution to the problem, there might be other ways to do it. But without seeing what the actual issue is, is difficult to give a more general answer.  For instance, in this question, how do you want to specify your requirements?